# Chamar qualquer função de outra classe de mesmo tipo

Tags: c++, funções, classes, ponteiro

Preciso passar como parâmetro para uma função membro outra função membro (mas de outra classe).
Consigo fazer isso para funções de mesma classe, mas de outra ainda não consegui

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void MyP(int a) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

class MyPrint {
public:
    void MyP(int a) {
        cout << a << endl;
    }


};

class MyClass {
public:

    void MyC(void (*Op)(int)) {
        Op(4);
    }

};

int main() {
    MyPrint A;
    MyClass P;

    P.MyC(MyP); // Funciona -> Pega a função normal (sem a classe) 
    P.MyC(A.MyP); // Não Funciona -> Pega a função membro (da classe)

    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: O problema é que o método `MyP` de `MyPrint` é um método de instância, logo precisa da referência ao objeto. Se o tornar estático vai ver que funciona.

Comment: Encontrei uma solução podendo chamar funções não estáticas dentro da classe amigo. Pus ela aqui[Call Ticker library from another class1](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/call-ticker-library-from-another-class1/888660)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que todo método de instância requer um objeto. Se ele fosse especificado como `static` funcionaria. Exemplo:

```
class MyPrint {
public:
    static void StaticMyP(int a) {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass P;

    P.MyC(&MyPrint::StaticMyP); // Funciona -> Pega o método estático (sem a classe)

    return 0;
}
```

Mas se você realmente quiser chamar o método do objeto `A` é necessário passar um ponteiro (ou referência) para o objeto em questão. Exemplo:

```
void MyP(int a) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

class MyPrint {
public:
    void MyP(int a) {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};

class MyClass {
public:
    void MyC(void (*Op)(int)) {
        Op(4);
    }

    void MyC(MyPrint *obj, void (MyPrint::*Op)(int)) {
        (obj->*Op)(4);
    }
};

int main() {
    MyPrint A;
    MyClass P;

    P.MyC(MyP); // Funciona -> Pega a função normal (sem a classe) 
    P.MyC(&A, &MyPrint::MyP); // Funciona -> Pega a função membro (da classe)

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Aqui retorna:

'void MyClass::MyC<MyPrint>(T *,void (__thiscall MyPrint::* )(int))':
não é possível converter um argumento 2 de 'void (__cdecl *)(int)' em 'void (__thiscall MyPrint::* )(int)'

Comment: Copiei e colei e fiz algumas pequenas alterações:
Retirei os ´__PRETTY_FUNCTION__´
Alterei o ´StaticMyP´ para só ´MyP´
No main ao invez de ´P.MyC(&A, &MyPrint::MyP);´ coloquei ´P.MyC<MyPrint>(&A, &MyPrint::MyP);

O resto está idêntico
Fiz estas alterações pq apareciam vários erros

Comment: Vou tentar compilar no Windows com _template_ para ver qual é o problema, mas enquanto isso vou atualizar o exemplo para usar tipo fixo.

Comment: Funcionou, coloquei o template agr e tbm deu